# Do a calculation on a specific index in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to code a small program to make my work easier, but I can't get my head around the last essential part. I am fairly new to python and super happy that I have come this far.

The code iterates through 6 pages and extracts information out of tables and gives it out.

What I need to do now is to calculate 1% to the 4th output value aka Loop Index 3 (564,09*1.01) - the rest should be put out without the calculation. I figure I need an `if else` statement in the last `for` loop, but I can't get it to work :(

My code is as follows:

```
# Import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

metalle = ['Ag_processed','Al_cables','Au_processed','DEL_low','MB_MS_63_wire','Pb_Cable']
urls = []
for i in metalle:
    url = 'http://somepage.com/yada.php?action=show_table&field=' + str(i)
    urls.append(url)

for y in urls:
    page = requests.get(y)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

# Remove links
    last_links = soup.find(class_='linkbar')
    last_links.decompose()
    years = soup.find(class_='year')
    years.decompose()

# Pull all text from the section div
    tabelle = soup.find(class_='section')

# Pull text from all instances of <tr> tag within section div, ignore first one, header 1:
    preise = tabelle.find_all('tr')[1:]

# Create for loop to print out all prices
    wert = []
    for tabelle in preise:
    #I FIGURE HERE IS A IF ELSE NEEDED
        preis = tabelle.contents[1]
        wert.append(preis.string)
    print(wert[0])

OUTPUT: 
474,60  
213,06  
38.550,00 
564,09 #THIS NEEDS TO BE CALCULATED +1%
557,00
199,55
```

I hope you can help a Python Newbie <3

Greetings Sandrigo

Comment: change from
`for y in urls:`
to 
`for (i, y) in enumerate(urls):`
and change from 
`#I FIGURE HERE IS A IF ELSE NEEDED`
to 
`if i==3:`

Comment: wow thx..i forgot about the upper FOR loop - i guess it works now, although the float conversion is not working now.. maybe you got a hint here too:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end of the code you can just

```
# format currency to valid number, from 38.550,00 to 38550.00 
wert[3] = wert[3].replace('.', '').replace(',', '.') 
wert[3] = float(wert[3]) * 1.01
print(wert)
```

Comment: i cant figure out where to put this, i think i need to do the calculation in the if i == 3 part of the loop because i only want to calculate this exact value..the rest should be printed normally through the outer loop

Comment: before `print(wert[0])` it is same if you using `if i == 3` or my code above, just try

Comment: ok i added it, its running normally but not calculating. it seems to me that i can't access indexes via wert[] - this is a list with only one value which gets put out through the for loop above (for my understanding)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the list `preise` into enumerate type using method `enumerate()`. It's mean, that if your list looks like this `["a", "b", "c"]`, you can convert it to `[(0, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "c"]`. So, your code must be look like this:

```
for i, tabelle in enumerate(preise):
    if i == 3:
       preis = tabelle.contents[1]*1.01
    else:
       preis = tabelle.contents[1]
    wert.append(preis.string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, thanks for everyones helped, i figured it out:

working solution:

```
for (i, y) in enumerate(urls):
    page = requests.get(y)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    last_links = soup.find(class_='linkbar')
    last_links.decompose()
    years = soup.find(class_='year')
    years.decompose()
    tabelle = soup.find(class_='section')
    preise = tabelle.find_all('tr')[1:]
    wert = []
    for tabelle in preise:
        if i == 3:
            preis = tabelle.contents[1]
            wert.append(preis.string)
            wert[0] = str(wert[0]).replace('.', '').replace(',', '.') 
            wert[0] = float(wert[0]) * 1.01
            wert[0] = str(wert[0]).replace('.', ',')
            break
        else:
            preis = tabelle.contents[1]
            wert.append(preis.string)   
    print(wert[0])

    file.write(str(wert[0]))
    file.write("\n")
file.close()
```

Thanks everyone!